# MySQL Search and Display Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-tables

I almost have this working but now I am officially stuck. I am trying to make the search area able to search by firstname, lastname, and id number. But I cannot get it to display all of them only one using this line in MySQL:

Here is the form:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="term" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

And Here is the line in the form.php I am trying to get to work from it:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rcrentals WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$term."%'";
```

WHERE firstname is at currently - I want this to search firstname, lastname, and id - not just the firstname.

I am missing something but I am not sure what. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Here is the full code. I think I was leaving out some stuff that you guys may need to help me out when I noticed my other variables. Please take a look at the whole code:

```
// Database Connection String
$con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>SpeedZone Data Search</title>
        <style type="text/css">
table { border-collapse:collapse; }
table td, table th { border:1px solid black;padding:5px; }
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #ffffff}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #ff0000}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
<form action="" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="term" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />  
</form>  
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rcrentals WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$term."%' OR lastname like '%".$term."%' OR id = ".$term;
$r_query = mysql_query($sql); 

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Address</th> <th>City</th> <th>State</th> <th>Zip</th> <th>Phone</th> <th>DL</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Car and Controller</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['address'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['city'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['st'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['zip'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['phone'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['dl'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['carcont'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
                // echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" onclick="return confirm(\'Confirm?\')">Delete</a></td>';
                echo "</tr>"; 
        } 

        // close table>
        echo "</table>"; 

}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rcrentals WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$term."%' or lastname like '%".$term."%' or id = ".$term;
```

Comment: Using that line: Now the ID is searchable, but not the firstname or lastname.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (Column1 LIKE SearchedText OR Column2 LIKE SearchedText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to match *ALL* the given criterion?

```
"SELECT * FROM rcrentals WHERE firstname LIKE '%{$term}%' AND lastname like '%{$term}%' AND id = {$term}";
```

Or **ANY** of the given criterion?

```
"SELECT * FROM rcrentals WHERE firstname LIKE '%{$term}%' OR lastname like '%{$term}%' OR id = {$term}";
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: That made none of the items searchable. I want to be able to input EITHER of the search terms in the one box and it search for them on the database. Either the firstname, lastname, or id, or all together.

Comment: The one you have for ANY given criterion works ONLY with the ID being searched. If I search name or lastname it doesnt work.

Comment: @user2503303 It doesn't make sense. Can you print the exact string being output by the above statement in your application?

Comment: I updated the entire php document up above. I think there is a few things that will need to be modified to actually make this work. Please take a look at the whole thing again up top.

Comment: @user2503303 Please add the *actual* value of $sql at run-time.

Comment: Is it in the updated form up top ? I just added the whole PHP file contents.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the actual value of $sql at run-time. Everything up above now posted is everything I have. I can see where there are a few things that will probably need to be changed, but the point I am at now, I am not sure what to change to make it work. Can you help me out ?